# Android Java Bad Words Filter

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, filter

I want to create bad words filter. And this my example code:

```
String name = "jack white";   // **NOT WORK** 
String name = "white";  // **WORK**
String lowername = name.toLowerCase();
String[] banned = { "name", "hello", "white"};

if (Arrays.asList(banned).contains(lowername)) {
true;
}
```

If name white function working but if name jack white, or xxx white, or white xxx function not working.

I want to make a bad word filter for users comments.

Comment: Can you be more detailed of what you want.

Comment: Contains compare whole entry not parts

Comment: This looks like a clbuttic problem.

Comment: I would recommend looking into Pattern and Pattern Matchers as well as regular expressions. These will help.

Comment: @chrylis: Yes, definitely. https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-

Comment: Updated @crammeur

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
static String string1 = "jack smith ran across the street";
static String string2 = "smith jumped";

public static boolean compareStrings(String one, String two){
    boolean helper = false;

    String[] string = one.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (two.contains(string[i])) {
            helper = true;
            System.out.println(string[i]);
        }
    }

    return helper;

}
```

And then to use it...

```
System.out.println(compareStrings(string1, string2));
```

This will print out...

```
smith
true
```

Comment: Hello i send only one string to array and if string on array i need true.

Comment: thats fine... just remove the word 'jumped'. it will still be true... the result is spitting out true because the word smith is contained in string1

Answer (score 1):

Yout need to break the inputted name up to individual words, and check each one against the banned words:
(side note: Using a set instead of an array would greatly improve performance here)

```
Set<String> banned = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("name", "hello", "white"));

boolean shouldBeBanned = 
    Arrays.stream(name.split("\\s")).map(String::toLowerCase).anyMatch(banned::contains);
```

**Edit:**

The same behavior could, of course, be achieved without API level 24, although it won't be as elegant:

```
boolean shouldBeBanned = false;
for (String word : name.split("\\s")) {
    if (banned.contains(word.toLowerCase()) {
        shouldBeBanned = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays.stream required API LEVEL 24.

Comment: @user1318741 indeed. See my edited answer for an equivalent solution that doesn't require API level 24.

Comment: Working when string white but when whites or white+anything not working. @Mureinik I want ban everything containts banned word.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing wrong `Arrays.asList(banned).contains(lowername)`. Look at to understand [list.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

I've have modified your code as below to make that work.

```
    String name = "jack white"; // **NOT WORK** 
    //String name = "white";  // **WORK**
    String lowername = name.toLowerCase();
    String[] banned = {"name", "hello", "white"};
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(banned);
    boolean status = hasBannedWords(data,lowername);
    Log.d("TAG",""+status);
```

Seperate method to check the word.

```
private boolean hasBannedWords(List<String> data, String sentence) {
    for(String item: data) {
        if(sentence.contains(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user1318741 your welcome, please let me know once you verify

Comment: Arrays.stream required API LEVEL 24. And i am using API LEVEL 16 :)

Comment: @user1318741 see the updated answer